# Modify curl command to ansible uri module

Tags: curl, ansible, uri, qualys

I've been trying to execute the following curl command through the ansible uri module
(the url, username, and password have been changed just for privacy)

```
curl -u "username:password" "https://company.abc.apps.company.eu/qps/rest/1.0/download/ca/downloadbinary/" --header "Content-Type: application/xml" --data-raw "<ServiceRequest><data><DownloadBinary><platform>LINUX_UBUNTU</platform><architecture>ARM_64</architecture></DownloadBinary></data></ServiceRequest>" -o file.deb
```

my current playbook task is:

```
- name: Download Binaries?
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://company.abc.apps.company.eu/qps/rest/1.0/download/ca/downloadbinary/
    url_username: username
    url_password: password
    force_basic_auth: true
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/xml
    body_format: raw 
    body: "<ServiceRequest><data><DownloadBinary><platform>LINUX_UBUNTU</platform><architecture>ARM_64</architecture></DownloadBinary></data></ServiceRequest>"
    dest: file.deb
```

The error message I am getting from the site is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://companty.abc.apps.company.eu/qps/xsd/1.0/ca/downloadbinary.xsd">
  <responseCode>OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED</responseCode>
  <responseErrorDetails>
    <errorMessage>Operation not supported for this object using this method.</errorMessage>
    <errorResolution>Refer to the QPS guide for authorized operation for this domain object.</errorResolution>
  </responseErrorDetails>
</ServiceResponse>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone was wondering, it is a POST method.  So, I needed to add `method: POST` as part of the module.

```
- name: Download Binaries?
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://company.abc.apps.company.eu/qps/rest/1.0/download/ca/downloadbinary/
    url_username: username
    url_password: password
    method: POST
    force_basic_auth: true
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/xml
    body_format: raw 
    body: "<ServiceRequest><data><DownloadBinary><platform>LINUX_UBUNTU</platform><architecture>ARM_64</architecture></DownloadBinary></data></ServiceRequest>"
    dest: file.deb
```